# Android reduce size of icon inside image view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-image, androidsvg

I have the following tabs in a List View , these are using an icon SVG inside an image view :

[image]

My problem is the SVG icon is very big and I need to resize it WITHOUT resizing the image view and its shape , I would like it something like this :

[image]

This is my code :

circle_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    
    <size
        android:width="160dp"
        android:height="160dp" />
    
</shape>
```

imageView:

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLearnsetType"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/placeholder"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```

Java:

```
        Integer color = PokemonUtils.getColorForType().get(convertedType);
        Drawable drawable = getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bug_type_icon);
        ivLearnsetType.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        ivLearnsetType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_shape);
        GradientDrawable ivDrawable = (GradientDrawable) ivLearnsetType.getBackground();
        ivDrawable.setColor(color);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use android:scaleType="centerInside" in Imageview

Answer (score 2):

Add this to app/build.gradle for support

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

in onCreate method add this.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Here's the full code...

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivLearnsetType"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/placeholder"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```

Hope this helps...Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: The icon didn't changed, its still big

Comment: @NexussimLements Use `fitXY` and change the size of `ImageView` if you can